# Connecting Xamarin to Python MySQL connector

Tags: c#, python, mysql, database, xamarin

I'm doing an Xamarin app, and I want to connect it to MySQL databse using Python connector, and I'm not sure how could I exchange information between C# Xamarin code and Python Connector. For example I'd want to send login that user has input in the Xamarin app to the database.

Python code:

```
import mysql.connector
import requests
from datetime import date, datetime,timedelta

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='root',
                                database='user_account', host='localhost', port='3310')

cursor = cnx.cursor()
params = {'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2', 'key3' : 'value3'}
r = self.request.GET.get('email')
print(r)

add_user = ("INSERT INTO login_info " "(email, password, date) " "VALUES (%s,%s,%s)")

user_data = (params[0], params[1], params[2])

cursor.execute(add_user, user_data)
cnx.commit()
cursor.close()

cnx.close()
```

C# code:

```
public static void AddUserToDatabase()
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost/login.py");
            NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection();
            postData.Add("email", "testEmail@email.com");
            postData.Add("password", "superTestPassword");
            postData.Add("date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
            Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(uri, postData));
        }
```

Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT: I misunderstood the purpose you were using MySQL for.*

Ok, for starters there are a great number of preexisting resources on the Internet and StackOverflow to help answer this very question.

[This is from a while back but should still work.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4797/i-am-trying-to-connect-with-mysql-using-php-api-webservice-and-save-the-result-into-datastore-thin-b)

**Do not establish a direct connection to your database in your app.**
Instead, go through web APIs or use systems like Azure. There are ways to extract the C# code from an application and they're frankly very common so if you have login credentials in your Xamarin code imagine them public.

Comment: Is using SQLite good to make a sign-up database(username, password, etc), ain't it client-sided?

Comment: Updated my answer. See if it helps.